# Where are my AVD's and how do I mount them

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

This is my first post so apologies if this a stupid question! I have had a quick google but came up with no solution.

I've just created my first avds but cant find where the user data images are stored (my os is ubuntu 14.04).

I would be very grateful if someone can let me where they are. And even more grateful if they could tell me how to mount them.

Thanks for any replies.

Comment: you create them by standard Android SDK Manager, console, genymotion, Andorid Studio. Please more details

Comment: Check %userdir%\.android\avd\ on Windows, and /usr/.android/avd/ on *nix.

Comment: For you, try the second one. Also, the userdata images should be under the specific folders referenced by the AVD's .ini/.cfg file under its directory where I mentioned. Mounting them requires a loop device mount. Check online.

Answer (score 1):

#### To find directory with AVD emulators:

Follow these steps:

1. Open your home directory
2. Press `Ctrl`+`H` to unhide hidden folders and files.
3. Choose folder `.android`

Your AVDs should be in `avd` folder inside `.android` folder

#### To mount any AVD emulator

From: [Is there a way to mount Android .img to access the AVD (Android Virtual Device) contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831440/is-there-a-way-to-mount-android-img-to-access-the-avd-android-virtual-device)

> You can just mount the device in Linux:
>
> ```
> sudo mount -o loop ~/.android/avd/<myvirt>/sdcard.img <destdir>
> ```

Hope it help